# How to set default display value for data gridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am using Data Grid View.
I have a list of object lets say.

```
class abc{
   public int i{get;set;}
   public long b{get;set;}
 }
 //in Form Load
 List<abc> objList = new List();
 listpopulate(); // populate the list.
 datgridvew.dtasource = objList;
```

I want to show  "-" where  `Objabc.i value = 0`
 and want to show "Good" where `Objabc.b = 1000` 
I tried cell default format but in vain.

Can you please help me out ?

Comment: What if Objabc.i value = 0 and Objabc.b = 1000?

Comment: As i mention earlier i Want to show "-" this if i value = 0 
and "Good" if b = 1000

Comment: You mean "-" in the i column and "good" in the b column or are you talking about the same column?

Comment: these are different.
let say here "i" mean Age Column. b  might b salary.
i can't show age = 0 if "i" = 0 in data grid view  but  want to show "-" rather then zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an event for that, like:

[`DataGridView.CellValueChanged Event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx)

Or use [DataGridView.CellFormatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting.aspx) Event like this:

```
private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "i" &&
        e.RowIndex >= 0 &&
        dgv["i", e.RowIndex].Value is int) &&
        (((int)dgv["i", e.RowIndex].Value) == 0)
        {
           e.Value = "-";
           e.FormattingApplied = true;           
        }
    }
    else if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "b" &&
        e.RowIndex >= 0 &&
        dgv["b", e.RowIndex].Value is int) &&
        (((int)dgv["b", e.RowIndex].Value) == 1000)
        {
           e.Value = "Good";
           e.FormattingApplied = true;           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it scanning all the cells of Grid view  with in for loop. at every cell value changed event. I can't bear this cost. what if i bind 10000 rows with grid view or more then this ?

Comment: You can check the DataGridViewImageCell for ColumnIndex and use the logic only for the specific columns

Comment: Check the update, this would not cost you as much as you think, the logic will only apply for the certain columns.

Answer (score -1):

HEre you can do using **`Jquery`** on **clientside**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
             $(".GRIDVIEWCLASSNAME").find("td").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).text() == "0")
                    {
                        $(this).html("-");
                    }
                     if ($(this).text() == "1000")
                    {
                        $(this).html("Good");
                    }
                });
        });
```

Comment: ! Your solution might work at asp.net Grid view.
but i am taking about data Grid View means Desktop application.